# How to remove rear wheel of old school Brompton 3-speed

Tags: brompton

I want to remove the rear wheel in order to replace the tire and tube.

How to detach the chain-tension cable on this old-school 3-speed Brompton? Does that black losenge-shaped thingie that is attached to small chain going into the rear hub simply get twisted off the threaded connector? Is that shiny clip somehow involved?

When I attempt to unthread the plastic piece from the threaded connector at the end of the hub chain, the chain-tension cable itself begins to untwist into separate strands.

[image: Old school 3-speed Brompton rear wheel]

Comment: That is an SRAM Spectro hub and adjuster.  I can't find specifics on how to manipulate it, but [this page](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/364269/Sram-Sram-Spectro-T3.html?page=14) has some info.

Comment: I think you have to press the shiny clip on the bottom right and then pull the threaded connector out. The threads are used to adjust the tension (similar to a barrel adjuster).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just press the metal clip and you can simply pull them apart (with very little force). Tipp: attach some tape to where the plastic part engages the threaded rod so you don't have to readjust the shifting when reassembling.